# How can I click the login image without Id or Name in website?

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I wanna write code via VBA to automatically login an website.

And the login "button" is actually a "login image", without id or Name.  I don't know how to make VBA do a "left mouse click" on the "login image".

Addtionally, I noticed when I move mouse onto the "login image", The left-bottom corner displays: `\smcvdol\logon`

may this help...I don't know about javascript at all

Here's it:

```
<TD align=right width="20%" height="21"><input type="image" src="../img/DL.jpg" width="63" height="22" border="0" onClick="javascript:submitform();" style="cursor: pointer;"></TD>
```

and here's the submitform():

```
<script> 
function submitform(){ 
if(FRM.authId.value==''){ 
alert("please enter user name!"); 
FRM.authId.focus(); 
return false; 
}else{ 
FRM.submit(); 
} 
} 
function reset_text(){ 
document.getElementById('username').focus(); 

} 
</script>
```

Here's my code, still missing the last step:('###the site is unaccessible out of our company###)

```
Sub macro1()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://10.90.15.247/smcvDolWeb/jsp/login.htm"

While ie.busy Or ie.readystate <> 4
Wend

ie.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "admin"
ie.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "1234"


End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've search the other questions that seems related to mine, but still confused as  there are something different. I saw on answer refered to "FireEvent("click")", but that still not work.

Comment: Get the object by type getElementsByTagName

Comment: Try FireEvent("Click")  Can you reference the form and submit it, that's all the JS script does, if you're adding the values, no need to validate, just call Form.Submit() the else part

Answer (score 0):

So this will loop through every TD item on the page. once it hits one with the same src it will click it.

If you don't want to do this everytime, and the webpage doesn't change a lot you can just debug.print the cnt and do ie.document.all.tags("td").item(cnt).click

Let me know if this works.

```
                            Dim Cnt         As Variant
                        Dim oCell       As Object
                                Cnt = 0  '
                                With ie.Document.all
                                    For Each oCell In .tags("td")
                                        If oCell.src = "../img/DL.jpg" Then
                                            ocell.click
                                            ocell.fireevent("submit") 'aircode, might have to be moved.
                                            Exit For
                                        End If
                                        Cnt = Cnt + 1
                                        Next oCell
                                    End With
```

also, it would probably work a little quicker if you replaced "td" with "image"

The javascript you need to run will be .fireevent("submit") or maybe even onchange.

Comment: Woh ! it's tag("td")  ?   I regarded it's TagName as "input" all the way.  (The page will never change even someday the GreatFrieWall falls.)

Comment: Did it work? I hope it worked, throw me and upvote if it worked. New to the site and trying to take over. But seriously, that loop has helped me isolate so many crazy hidden little elements on pages. I used to have one thats sole purpose was do debug.print attributes of every tagged item on the page. It's a life saver.

Comment: Already upvoted ~ but can's seen publically as my reputation not enough.  I have to try tomorrow , in office. thx

Comment: @grantpanda well, let me know if you need any other VBA/IE automation help. It's my bread and butter.

Comment: I've tried and didn't success. But still thanks a lot. I finally solve the problem by using " ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).submit. :)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know there was a form element in the html. Yea, things that your going to have to drill through are forms and frames. Those two elements have to be identified in order to hook into whats inside of them.If you add the form element to the loop above it would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Get the object by type getElementsByTagName and then loop for the correct one

Comment: thx...'IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(3).click' I tried this But it went wrong warning " The element has no such method".

Comment: Are you sure it's the right one?  presuming (1) is the start username, (2) being password.  How many elements are in `IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")`

Comment: Oh..I see.  It's the 4th element stared with "input".  I counted from 0 in C way.

Comment: Use your locals window, as some base 0 some base 1